# Distinguishing between a predictor's between and within contributions

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a continuous predictor that can vary between `studies` and `outcomes` in a 3-level linear mixed model like:

`y ~ X + (1 | studies/outcomes)`

How can I fit a model to distinguish between $X$'s between and within contributions across `studies` and `outcomes`?

## PS:

In 2-level models (e.g., `y ~ X + (1 | studies)`), we can do this by creating 2 variables out of $X$ within each level of `studies`:

```
data %>% group_by(studies) %>% mutate(X_between = mean(X), X_within = X-X_between)
```

And use them as fixed effects:

`y ~ X_between + X_within + (1 | studies)`

Comment: Interesting (+1). I have thought about this a little but haven't reached any conclusion. With one grouping variable we just fit the group means as a between variable and the deviations from the group means as within. Did you try doing the same with 2 grouping variables ? Were the results sensible ?

Comment: @RobertLong, I can think of two options but wonder which one makes more sense. **Option 1:** Create mean of X across studies (`X_ave_study`) and mean of X across outcomes *ignoring* studies (`X_ave_outcome`). **Option 2**: Create mean of X across studies and mean of X across outcomes *within* studies (`X_ave_outcome`). For both options, then, I will fit:

`y ~ X + X_ave_study + X_ave_outcome + (1 | studies/outcomes)` . . .

Comment: @RobertLong, . . . In R code: `#-- Option 1: 
    data %>%
    group_by(studies) %>%
    mutate(X_ave_study = mean(X)) %>%
    group_by(outcomes) %>%    
    mutate(X_ave_outcome = mean(X))

#-- Option 2:
  data %>%
  group_by(studies) %>%
  mutate(X_ave_study = mean(X)) %>%
  group_by(outcomes, .add = TRUE) %>%  
  mutate(X_ave_outcome = mean(X))`

Comment: @RobertLong, did you possibly have any opinion on the two options presented by Reza above?